# How to set an "on outside click" action on a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I want to execute a code before closing my dialog fragment when touching it outside. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I tried to override "onDismiss" method, but the DialogFragment is dismissed before writing the log.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Dialog will be dismissed");
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Comment: onDismiss listener ?

Comment: I already tried that, but I receive this message on logcat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: "You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener"

Comment: that's true. You can always override onDismiss in your DialogFragment's subclass

Answer (score 0):

Override setOnDismissListener(...) method of class Dialog

Comment: I already tried that, but I receive this message on logcat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: "You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener"

Comment: Override onDismiss or onCancel, since setoOnDismissListener should not be overriden for Custom dialogs

Comment: Yes, it is a custom one. Didn't knew it would make a difference. Anyway my problem keeps unsolved because the dialog always closes before executing the code I want.

Comment: Can you share the snippet?